# Typing Python sequence to Cython array (and back)

Tags: python, arrays, byte, sequence, cython

I have successfully used Cython for the first time to significantly speed up packing nibbles from one list of integers (*bytes*) into another (see [Faster bit-level data packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47371520/faster-bit-level-data-packing)), e.g. packing the two sequential bytes `0x0A` and `0x0B` into `0xAB`.

```
def pack(it):
    """Cythonize python nibble packing loop, typed"""
    cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
    cdef unsigned int i
    return [ (it[i*2]//16)<<4 | it[i*2+1]//16 for i in range(n) ]
```

While the resulting speed is satisfactory, I am curious whether this can be taken further by making better use of the input and output lists.

`cython3 -a pack.cyx` generates a very "cythonic" HTML report that I unfortunately am not experienced enough to draw any useful conclusions from.

From a C point of view the loop should "simply" access two unsigned int arrays. Possibly, using a wider data type (16/32 bit) could further speed this up proportionally.

The question is: (how) can [Python [binary/immutable] sequence types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview) be typed as `unsigned int array` for Cython?

---

Using array as suggested in [How to convert python array to cython array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689967/) does not seem to make it faster (and the array needs to be created from bytes object beforehand), nor does typing the parameter as `list` instead of `object` (same as no type) or using for loop instead of list comprehension:

```
def packx(list it):
    """Cythonize python nibble packing loop, typed"""
    cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef list r = [0]*n
    for i in range(n):
        r[i] = (it[i*2]//16)<<4 | it[i*2+1]//16
    return r
```

---

I think my earlier test just specified an array.array as input, but following the comments I've now just tried

```
from cpython cimport array
import array

def packa(array.array a):
    """Cythonize python nibble packing loop, typed"""
    cdef unsigned int n = len(a)//2
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef unsigned int b[256*64/2]
    for i in range(n):
        b[i] = (a[i*2]//16)<<4 | a[i*2+1]//16;

    cdef array.array c = array.array("B", b)
    return c
```

which compiles but

```
ima = array.array("B", imd) # unsigned char (1 Byte)
pa = packa(ima)
packed = pa.tolist()
```

segfaults.
I find the documentation a bit sparse, so any hints on what the problem is here and how to allocate the array for output data are appreciated.

---

Taking @ead's first approach, plus combining division and shifting (seems to save a microsecond:

```
#cython: boundscheck=False, wraparound=False

def packa(char[::1] a):
    """Cythonize python nibble packing loop, typed with array"""

    cdef unsigned int n = len(a)//2
    cdef unsigned int i

    # cdef unsigned int b[256*64/2]
    cdef array.array res = array.array('B', [])
    array.resize(res, n)

    for i in range(n):
        res.data.as_chars[i] = ( a[i*2] & 0xF0 ) | (a[i*2+1] >> 4);

    return res
```

compiles much longer, but runs much faster:

```
python3 -m timeit -s 'from pack import packa; import array; data = array.array("B", bytes([0]*256*64))' 'packa(data)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 236 usec per loop
```

Amazing! But, with the additional bytes-to-array and array-to-list conversion

```
ima = array.array("B", imd) # unsigned char (1 Byte)
pa = packa(ima)
packed = pa.tolist() # bytes would probably also do
```

it now only takes about 1.7 ms - very cool!

---

Down to 150 us timed or approx. 0.4 ms actual:

```
from cython cimport boundscheck, wraparound
from cpython cimport array
import array

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def pack(const unsigned char[::1] di):
    cdef:
        unsigned int i, n = len(di)
        unsigned char h, l, r
        array.array do = array.array('B')

    array.resize(do, n>>1)

    for i in range(0, n, 2):
        h = di[i] & 0xF0
        l = di[i+1] >> 4
        r = h | l
        do.data.as_uchars[i>>1] = r

    return do
```

I'm not converting the result array to a list anymore, this is done automatically by py-spidev when writing, and the total time is about the same: 10 ms (@ 10 MHz).

Comment: Have you tried the plain numpy approach: `np.array(it,dtype=np.uint8).view(dtype=np.uint16)`?

Comment: @DavidW Would this not just result in `0x0A0B`? Then it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: @DavidW It results in decimal 2826 (`0x0B0A`, depending on endianess). But thanks for the input!

Comment: Do you really know, what is slowing your down? Measure it first, and you will be surprised! You approach is `python-ints->c-ints->calc new c-ints->create-python ints` I didn't measure, but my guess would be that the last step `c-ints->reate-python-ints` is the bottle neck (but as I didn't measure it, I maybe mistaken). There is no gain in speeding up  the calcultion with c-ints. The only way I see is to use `array.array`  (or numpy array) instead of list in your python-program, so the last step isn't needed.

Comment: You're right - this can't be done by reinterpretting the memory I think

Comment: @ead No, I don't know whether there is a bottleneck left that could be worked around. I don't know how to partially measure either. I've added a small C equivalent to my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47375829/1619432 that I think is about a 100  times faster. Using array actually was slower (also, it requires conversion from bytes).

Comment: Then please post your `array.array`-version, i.e. a function which takes `array.array('c',...)-object` or `char[::1]` for that matter and returns `array.array('c', ...)`-object. I would really like to see, why it is not faster than your current version.

Comment: @ead I tried and failed ('c' does not seem to be valid). Please have a look at my updated question. I'll try to post an [mcve] in a couple of hours.

Comment: For those following these comments: it's pretty much worked out - see the updated question and ead's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanna to be as fast as C you should not use list with python-integers inside but an `array.array`. It is possible to get a speed-up of around 140 for your python+list code by using cython+`array.array`.

Here are some ideas how to make your code faster with cython. As benchmark I choose a list with 1000 elements (big enough and cache-misses have no effects yet):

```
import random
l=[random.randint(0,15) for _ in range(1000)]
```

As baseline, your python-implementation with list:

```
def packx(it):
    n = len(it)//2
    r = [0]*n
    for i in range(n):
        r[i] = (it[i*2]%16)<<4 | it[i*2+1]%16
    return r

%timeit packx(l)
143 µs ± 1.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

By the way, I use `%` instead of `//`, which is probably what you want, otherwise you would get only `0`s as result (only lower bits have data in your description).

After cythonizing the same function (with `%%cython`-magic) we get a speed-up of around 2:

```
%timeit packx(l)
77.6 µs ± 1.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Let's look at the html produced by option `-a`, we see the following for the line corresponding to the `for`-loop:

```
..... 
__pyx_t_2 = PyNumber_Multiply(__pyx_v_i, __pyx_int_2); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
 __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
 __pyx_t_5 = PyObject_GetItem(__pyx_v_it, __pyx_t_2); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_5)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
 __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_5);
 __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
 __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyInt_RemainderObjC(__pyx_t_5, __pyx_int_16, 16, 0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 6, __pyx_L1_error)
...
```

`Py_NumberMultiply` means that we use slow python-multiplication, `Pyx_DECREF`- all temporaries are slow python-objects. We need to change that!

Let's pass not a list but an `array.array` of bytes to our function and return an `array.array` of bytes back. Lists have full fledged python objects inside, `array.array`the lowly raw c-data which is faster:

```
%%cython
from cpython cimport array
def cy_apackx(char[::1] it):
    cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef array.array res = array.array('b', [])
    array.resize(res, n)
    for i in range(n):
        res.data.as_chars[i] = (it[i*2]%16)<<4 | it[i*2+1]%16
    return res

import array
a=array.array('B', l)
%timeit cy_apackx(a)
19.2 µs ± 316 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Better, but let take a look at the generated html, there is still some slow python-code:

```
 __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_long(((__Pyx_mod_long((*((char *) ( /* dim=0 */ ((char *) (((char *) __pyx_v_it.data) + __pyx_t_7)) ))), 16) << 4) | __Pyx_mod_long((*((char *) ( /* dim=0 */ ((char *) (((char *) __pyx_v_it.data) + __pyx_t_8)) ))), 16))); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 9, __pyx_L1_error)
__Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
 if (unlikely(__Pyx_SetItemInt(((PyObject *)__pyx_v_res), __pyx_v_i, __pyx_t_2, unsigned int, 0, __Pyx_PyInt_From_unsigned_int, 0, 0, 1) < 0)) __PYX_ERR(0, 9, __pyx_L1_error)
 __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
```

We still use a python-setter for array (`__Pax_SetItemInt`) and for this a python objecct `__pyx_t_2` is needed, to avoid this we use `array.data.as_chars`:

```
%%cython
from cpython cimport array
def cy_apackx(char[::1] it):
    cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef array.array res = array.array('B', [])
    array.resize(res, n)
    for i in range(n):
        res.data.as_chars[i] = (it[i*2]%16)<<4 | it[i*2+1]%16  ##HERE!
return res

%timeit cy_apackx(a)
1.86 µs ± 30.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Much better, but let's take a look at html again, and we see some calls to `__Pyx_RaiseBufferIndexError` - this safety costs some time, so let's switch it off:

```
%%cython
from cpython cimport array    
import cython
@cython.boundscheck(False) # switch of safety-checks
@cython.wraparound(False) # switch of safety-checks
def cy_apackx(char[::1] it):
    cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef array.array res = array.array('B', [])
    array.resize(res, n)
    for i in range(n):
        res.data.as_chars[i] = (it[i*2]%16)<<4 | it[i*2+1]%16  ##HERE!
    return res

%timeit cy_apackx(a)
1.53 µs ± 11.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

When we look at the generated html, we see:

```
__pyx_t_7 = (__pyx_v_i * 2);
__pyx_t_8 = ((__pyx_v_i * 2) + 1);
(__pyx_v_res->data.as_chars[__pyx_v_i]) = ((__Pyx_mod_long((*((char *) ( /* dim=0 */ ((char *) (((char *) __pyx_v_it.data) + __pyx_t_7)) ))), 16) << 4) | __Pyx_mod_long((*((char *) ( /* dim=0 */ ((char *) (((char *) __pyx_v_it.data) + __pyx_t_8)) ))), 16));
```

No python-stuff! Good so far. However, I'm not sure about `__Pyx_mod_long`, its definition is:

```
static CYTHON_INLINE long __Pyx_mod_long(long a, long b) {
   long r = a % b;
   r += ((r != 0) & ((r ^ b) < 0)) * b;
   return r;
}
```

So C and Python have differences for `mod` of negative numbers and it must be taken into account. This function-definition, albeit inlined, will prevent the C-compiler from optimizing `a%16` as `a&15`. We have only positive numbers, so no need to care about them, thus we need to do the `a&15`-trick by ourselves:

```
%%cython
from cpython cimport array
import cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def cy_apackx(char[::1] it):
    cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef array.array res = array.array('B', [])
    array.resize(res, n)
    for i in range(n):
        res.data.as_chars[i] = (it[i*2]&15)<<4 | (it[i*2+1]&15)
    return res

%timeit cy_apackx(a)
1.02 µs ± 8.63 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

I'm also satified with the resulting C-code/html (only one line):

```
(__pyx_v_res->data.as_chars[__pyx_v_i]) = ((((*((char *) ( /* dim=0 */ ((char *) (((char *) __pyx_v_it.data) + __pyx_t_7)) ))) & 15) << 4) | ((*((char *) ( /* dim=0 */ ((char *) (((char *) __pyx_v_it.data) + __pyx_t_8)) ))) & 15));
```

**Conclusion:** In the sum that means speed up of 140 (140 µs vs 1.02 µs)- not bad! Another interesting point: the calculation itself takes about 2 µs (and that comprises less than optimal bound checking and division) - 138 µs are for creating, registering and deleting temporary python objects.

---

If you need the upper bits and can assume that lower bits are without dirt (otherwise `&250` can help), you can use:

```
from cpython cimport array
import cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def cy_apackx(char[::1] it):
    cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef array.array res = array.array('B', [])
    array.resize(res, n)
    for i in range(n):
        res.data.as_chars[i] = it[i*2] | (it[i*2+1]>>4)
    return res

%timeit cy_apackx(a)
819 ns ± 8.24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

---

Another interesting question is which costs have the operations if list is used. If we start with the "improved" version:

```
%%cython
def cy_packx(it):
    cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
    cdef unsigned int i
    res=[0]*n
    for i in range(n):
        res[i] = it[i*2] | (it[i*2+1]>>4))
    return res

%timeit cy_packx(l)
20.7 µs ± 450 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

we see, that reducing the number of integer operation leads to a big speed-up. That is due to the fact, that python-integers are immutable and every operation creates a new temporary object, which is costly. Eliminating operations means also eliminating costly temporaries.

However, `it[i*2] | (it[i*2+1]>>4)` is done with python-integer, as next step we make it `cdef`-operations:

```
%%cython   
def cy_packx(it):
    cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef unsigned char a,b
    res=[0]*n
    for i in range(n):
        a=it[i*2]
        b=it[i*2+1]  # ensures next operations are fast
        res[i]= a | (b>>4)
    return res   

    %timeit cy_packx(l)
    7.3 µs ± 880 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

I don't know how it can be improved further, thus we have 7.3 µs for list vs. 1 µs for `array.array`.

---

Last question, what is the costs break down of the list version? I  order to avoid being optimized away by the C-compiler, we use a slightly different baseline function:

```
%%cython
def cy_packx(it):
        cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
        cdef unsigned int i
        cdef unsigned char a,b
        cdef unsigned char s = 0
        res=[0]*n
        for i in range(n):
            a=it[i*2]
            b=it[i*2+1]  # ensures next operations are fast
            s+=a | (b>>4)
            res[i]= s
        return res
%timeit cy_packx(l)

In [79]: %timeit cy_packx(l)
7.67 µs ± 106 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The usage of  the `s` variable means, it does not get optimized away in the second version:

```
%%cython   
def cy_packx(it):
        cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
        cdef unsigned int i
        cdef unsigned char a,b
        cdef unsigned char s = 0
        res=[0]*n
        for i in range(n):
            a=it[i*2]
            b=it[i*2+1]  # ensures next operations are fast
            s+=a | (b>>4)
        res[0]=s
        return res 

In [81]: %timeit cy_packx(l)
5.46 µs ± 72.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

About 2 µs or about 30% are the costs for creating new integer objects. What are the costs of the memory allocation?

```
%%cython   
def cy_packx(it):
        cdef unsigned int n = len(it)//2
        cdef unsigned int i
        cdef unsigned char a,b
        cdef unsigned char s = 0
        for i in range(n):
            a=it[i*2]
            b=it[i*2+1]  # ensures next operations are fast
            s+=a | (b>>4)
        return s 

In [84]: %timeit cy_packx(l)
3.84 µs ± 43.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

That leads to the following performance break down of the list-version:

```
                    Time(in µs)      Percentage(in %)
     all                7.7                 100
     calculation          1                  12
     alloc memory       1.6                  21
     create ints        2.2                  29
     access data/cast   2.6                  38
```

I must confess, I expected `create ints` to play a bigger role and didn't thing accessing the data in the list and casting it to `char`s will cost that much.

Comment: Thank you! I'll only be able to test in about 20 hrs. Source data will be 8 bits but needs to be reduced to 4 bits, thus the division by 16 (equivalent to >> 4, so further optimization possible). `0x0A` was meant to show the nibbles clearly. I will update accordingly. In the meantime, could you point me to documentation on the `char[::1] it` slicing syntax?

Comment: @handle you can take a look at typed memory views: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

Comment: @handle I also improved the list-version somewhat, it might still be an option for you.

Comment: Thanks again, down to 1.7 ms for the whole conversion via array (see updated question). Will look into your further improvements in about 8 hrs.

Comment: The array (conversion) should not be necessary as Cython is supposed to support `bytes` as either char* or memoryview, unfortunately I also get this error: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1682. It works with `bytearray`though I yet have to figure out how to return the computed data.

Comment: @handle Yeah, I'm sometimes overusing `array.array`, however the difference is not that big compared to `bytearray`. I don't know how you use the data in your program. But usually one tries to use `bytearray`or `array.array` + cython for calculations and avoids `list`s if possible in the whole program.

Comment: They seem to have a [fix for this almost ready](https://github.com/cython/cython/pull/1869), in the meantime I'll see if I can get the same perfomance with `bytearray` as with `array.array`. I get `bytes`from Pillow (PIL) and write them to a SPI with [py-spidev](https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev/blob/master/spidev_module.c#L121) which [optionally converts the sequence data to a list](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#c.PySequence_Fast), copies the data to a C-type  buffer which then is written to the SPI device (so there's room for improvement as well).

Comment: Further speedup by eliminating multiplication with a step-2 loop and rshift instead of division to get target index, now at 150 us timed and 420 us actual. bytearray or array.array do indeed not make much of a difference, if anything, array is slightly faster. Thanks again, I might revisit this once Cython is fixed.

Comment: Cython seems to have been fixed ([#1682](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1682)) but I'll wait for a release to play with this again...